# Updating a reducer from another reducer in react-native

Tags: react-native, redux

I want to update the state of one reducer from another reducer in react-native.My code is like this.

This is the action.

```
export const doLike = payload => {
  // Recieving response from the server
  let updatedPost = {
    Id: 1,
    userId: 1,
    postId: payload.post._id,
    __v: 1,
    count: payload.type === 1 ? 10 : 1
  };

  return {
    type: SM_ACTION_LIKE,
    post: updatedPost
  };
};
```

This is the smReducer which accepts the action.

```
const initialState = {
  post: {}
};

const smReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SM_ACTION_LIKE:
      return {
        ...state,
        post: action.post
      };
      break;

    default:
      return state;
  }

  return state;
};

export default smReducer;
```

Now I want to change the posts array of mainFeedReducer from here. My mainFeedReducer is this. I want to access the posts array of mainFeedReducer from smReducer.

```
const initialState = Immutable({
  posts: [],
  featuredWorkouts: []
});

const mainfeedReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_MAIN_FEED:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: action.mainFeedData.posts,
        featuredWorkouts: action.mainFeedData.featuredWorkouts
      };
      break;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Redux architecture revolves around a **strict unidirectional data flow**.

The correct way would be to design your reducers in such a way that they handle more data.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers#reducers-share-state)

If a reducer needs to know data from *another slice of state*, the *state tree shape* may need to be **reorganized** so that *a single reducer is handling more of the data*.

**Alternatives**

- You may consider using **[redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)**, since the inner
  function, that recieves two parameters `return (dispatch, getState)`,
  has an access to the **entire state map**.
- If you have an instance of your `store` object, then you can directly access at the states by doing `store.getState()`